# Limit of Summation of series

Tags: limits

$r$th term of a series is $t_r=\frac{r}{1-r^2+r^4}$. Then how do we compute $\lim_{n \to \infty }\sum_{r=1}^n t_r$.

I tried converting the summation into a definite integral so as to use Newton Leibnitz theorem , but was unable to do so. I don't see how to incorporate "$n$" into the general term. Please somebody help. It would be very helpful if someone gives the full solution as I am attempting such a summation - based limit question for the first time.

Comment: If you're having trouble with formatting, you can consult https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. For a more short term solution, you could give an online editor a shot, for instance https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php Your question seems fairly unintelligible right now.

Comment: Hey no need to bother , I have solved it .Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AurojeetJena How can you compute that? It is easy to see that the limit has an upper and lower bound. But it is not easy to see its exact value.

Answer (score 0):

First compute the sum of series upto n terms using "Method of Difference" ,then put the value , that includes "n" as variable in the limit.